# get/set cover for mp3 file in golang

Tags: go, mp3

I have an mp3 file and, when I load it in a media player, the media player displays the cover of the album. I presume the cover is in the file's metadata, so I'm wondering if there's a way to get to that cover in golang.

How do I set cover for mp3 file?

Comment: Hi Please refer this page for asking good question which usually get upvoted,which helps in getting good answer [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of this property is [ID3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3#ID3v2_embedded_image_extension).

You can use Library [dhowden/tag](https://github.com/dhowden/tag) to do this.

```
m, err := tag.ReadFrom(f)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
log.Print(m.Format()) // The detected format.
log.Print(m.Title())  // The title of the track (see Metadata interface for more details).
```

type of `m.Picture()` is Picture...

enjoy it!

another lib :
 - https://github.com/mikkyang/id3-go